# How do I add my PWA to the share sheet on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, share, progressive-web-apps

I was wondering if it is possible to add my PWA to the share sheet of a mobile device.

[image: iOS share sheet]

The [Web Share API](https://web.dev/web-share/) seems to be the 'opposite' of what I need.

Is there a way add a PWA to the share sheet in iOS or Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, you can use the [Web Share Target API](https://web.dev/web-share-target/) on android with Chrome 76 or later.
At the moment, the API has only a [draft status](https://w3c.github.io/web-share-target/).